# Center of a circumference?

Tags: geometry

Does the circumference have a center?, I mean the center of a triangle is a point in the triangle that will always occupy the same position under the operations of rotation, reflection, and dilation and the same for a square; but a circumference is a 1D object and the center wouldn't be in it, rather in the circle that it's determined by the circumference.

Comment: How do you define "circumference?" Usually it is a measure - a single real number - not a geometric object like a triangle...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : That usage is conventional in recent decades, but maybe your comment is a bit like naive people thinking the word "radius" means the distance from the center to the circle rather than a radius being any line segment with one endpoint at the center and one on the circle.  (But I think the person posting this question does seem confused.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy But it is the conventional meaning, which is what I said. Words mean what they mean, and circumference is a measure, not a set of points. ("Circumference of a circle" can hardly just mean "the circle.")

Comment: But "circumference" in common use can mean "perimeter", which, although as taught in math courses, means a "measure" rather than a geometric object, but in common use outside of mathematics can also mean a geometric and geographic object.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker but where I live it's defined as a plane curve: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circunferencia, moreover here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle it´s said to be a bounding line, not just a distance

Answer (score 1):

The circumference $C=2\pi r$, where $r$ is the radius, is merely the distance measured around the circle. The circumference cannot have a center.  The circle itself, however, does have a center.